# Apollo useQuery: API is working well but data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm using apollo-boost as my client. My useQuery hook works strangely, and I'm asking question here.

```
const { loading, data, refetch } = useQuery(SEARCH, {
    variables: {
      query: term,
    },
    skip: !shouldFetch,
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });
  console.log(loading, data);
```

This is my useQuery code. If data is empty, it console logs well. However, if there is some data fetched data becomes undefined.

**case 1(if fetched data is empty):**

network response:

```
{data: {readPosts: []}}
data: {readPosts: []}
readPosts: []
```

console:

> false {readPosts: Array(0)}

**case 2(if there is fetched data):**

network response:

```
data: {,…}}
data: {,…}
readPosts: [{id: "25", photos: [], title: "예시 제목2", price: 1234, user: {major: "", __typename: "User"},…}]
0: {id: "25", photos: [], title: "예시 제목2", price: 1234, user: {major: "", __typename: "User"},…}
```

console:

> false undefined

It is very weird because it seems there isn't any typo because it works well in case 1. However, how come it works strangely in case 2?

Comment: `data` will remain undefined if there are errors. Is there an `errors` array being returned in the response?

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks!! There was null in the response. I suceed to fix. Thank you very much.